# I need an adjective to precede the word "commitment"

Tags: single-word-requests

I'm looking for an adjective that has a close meaning to *strong*, *undying*, *relentless*...

> the school’s **__** commitment to bring change.

I'm writing a personal statement for a school.

Comment: You can spoil good writing by using too many adjectives. That phrase reads nicely without one.

Comment: Can I use unrestrained commitment?

Comment: @Neon Isn't *commitment* itself a restraint?

Answer (score 5):

Some of the words above, though apppropriate,  do seem a bit hyperbolic. Based on your real level of commitment,

> Firm

might be a good option as well. It indicates a strong commitment but not something that is necessarily on the same lines as eternal / unwavering etc

Answer (score 4):

- unwavering
- undying
- relentless

Comment: Two of these were in the OP's post.

Answer (score 3):

- unfaltering
- constant
- continual
- unwavering
- eternal

Answer (score 2):

- ongoing
- steadfast
- passionate
- wholehearted
- abiding

Answer (score 2):

I can think of two words to emphasise the meaning. Per Wiktionary, these are:

1- **[Deep](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/deep)** commitment

> Profound, having great meaning or import

2- [**Genuine**](http://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/british/genuine) commitment

> Real, rather than pretended or false

Answer (score 1):

What about *strong*, *intense*, or *abiding*?

Regardless of the adjective, though, this phrase might come off as a little "overpandering [sic]."  Maybe go with something a little less heady, like

> ...the school's long history of growing along with its students and with the community...